# Structure of a Record which has a text column

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a record which I viewed using DBCC page command. Here is how it looks:

```
Memory Dump @0x00E5C060

00000000:   30000800 01000000 02000001 001f8000 †0...............         
00000010:   00d10700 0000009a 00000001 000000††††...............          

Slot 0 Column 0 Offset 0x4 Length 4

col1 = 1                             

col2 = [Textpointer] Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0xf Length 16

TextTimeStamp = 131137536            RowId = (1:154:0)
```

Here `col1` is of type `int` and `col2` is of type `ntext`.
I know that `ntext` column values are stored in text page.

But I don't know how to interpret col2 info above, i.e.

```
col2 = [Textpointer] Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0xf Length 16

TextTimeStamp = 131137536            RowId = (1:154:0)
```

Can anybody help me understand this?

---

Thanks for replying,

```
 "col2 = [Textpointer] Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0xf Length 16"

00000000:   30000800 01000000 02000001 001f8000 †0...............
00000010:   00d10700 0000009a 00000001 000000††††...............
```

In this, it's said that the length of info is 16.
Its equivalent hex values are:

```
00 00d10700 0000009a 00000001 000000†††
```

I can find information about

```
TextTimeStamp = 131137536            RowId = (1:154:0)
```

in the above hex values. But how can I find info that it is a text pointer?

Moreover, in another instance, I came across `[Inline Blob root]` for an nvarchar datatype value.

Here's how it looked:

```
col6= [BLOB Inline Root] Slot 1 Column 38 Offset 0x16d Length 24

Level = 0                            Unused = 0                           UpdateSeq = 1
TimeStamp = 1969553408               
Link 0
```

Here if you notice the length is 24 in contrast to the previous instance (Text pointer)
It has some additional information as well like update sequence is 
UpdateSeq = 1.

How can I differentiate between the two instances by looking at the sequence of bytes?

Answer (score 1):

col2 is a pointer to the BLOB allocation unit. The ntext column is on slot 0 on the page (1:154). You can DBCC dump the page 1:154 to find the content of the ntext column col2.

There is a more detailed example at http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/12/13/More-undocumented-fun_3A00_-DBCC-IND_2C00_-DBCC-PAGE_2C00_-and-off_2D00_row-columns.aspx